# how can i run shell in workflow in oozie when i need to call pig in that shell?

Tags: oozie

In oozie I need to run a shell, I can run a normal shell, but now I need to call pig in shell, when the shell is running, it occurs errors, saying that can't find pig. So the problem is the machine running oozie doesn't know where the pig is. I can't run the pig directly as i need a loop of that pig in shell.Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set true the following properties and rerun the pig action:

use.system.libpath.for.mapreduce.and.pig.jobs

Answer (score 0):

Try to point the library path to the default oozie library for pig.
You will have to give teh full path, i was also having same issue but got it resolved, you can check for path in Oozie configuration .xml file.